unable to connect after dhcp to nfs in kickstart ubuntu 22.04
I am facing an issue where the client VM successfully gets an IP from DHCP, but fails to connect to the NFS server during the Kickstart installation process on my Ubuntu 22.04 server. Could anyone please assist with resolving this problem?
Thank you in advance for your help.
